# SAM4E16C MAC and PHY(ksz8081mnx) initialization

Tags: embedded, ethernet, atmel, atmelstudio

Hello to everyone I have a problem which is initializing the MAC and PHY(ksz8081mnx) on SAM4E16c. The main goal is to see if I can get information from the ethernet but unfortunately, I do not know how to read the data from the ethernet. I am new in this I hope someone can give me some tips to follow.

The tools that I am using are Atmel Studio IDE and Atmel ICE programming tool. The project I created is with Atmel Software Framework (ASF). I installed all drivers needed for the MAC and PHY (ksz8081mnx). I followed the "Quickstart guide for GMAC driver" which is on this website:
http://asf.atmel.com/docs/3.35.1/sam4e/html/gmac_quickstart.html

I uploaded the sketch and I tested it by looking at the router's client list if I can see the MAC address but I did not. I not sure if this is the right way of doing it but I had to try.

I not sure if I initialized the board as it should be. I took the [board_init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX9QX.png) example from (sam4e16e xplained pro ASF).

These GMAC peripheral registers are in the SAM4E16C.H file and they are corresponding with the (ksz8081mnx) chip but there are not used anywhere.
Should I set them in the board_init somehow or should I leave it like it is shown in the first picture?
[PIO definition for GMAC peripheral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeCZr.png)

These pictures are showing the Ethernet chip connection to the processor:

[Schematics Ethernet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baX9T.jpg)
[Schematics µC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9637Z.jpg)

Thank you, I am looking forward to your suggestions.

:)

Comment: You should probably try the Raw HTTP example first just to make sure everything works.

Comment: as @DKrueger said, the `LWIP raw http example` from ASF for SAM4E-EK is probably the best approach. Your pin init looks fine (you can compare it to the raw http example). Please post your gmac initialization code aswell so we can see what's wrong there.

Comment: The problem was in the hardware. So now I am working on with evaluation board just to make sure that the code is working.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all read the all ENET gmac controller register, you are able to access these controller register or not.

ENET_BASE_ADDR - Base address of gmac controller. 
ex `val = readl(ENET_BASE_ADDR + offset);`

- Configure the registers which are responsible in ENET operation.
  eg: Network control, network config register, PHY management register, Transmit status register, Receive status register,Tx Queue pointer, Rx Queue pointer.
- Most important register where we need to configure the 6 byte MAC address.

`#define ETHERNET_CONF_ETHADDR0 0x00`
`#define ETHERNET_CONF_ETHADDR1 0x04`

```
#define ETHERNET_CONF_ETHADDR2 0x25

#define ETHERNET_CONF_ETHADDR3 0x1C

#define ETHERNET_CONF_ETHADDR4 0xA0

#define ETHERNET_CONF_ETHADDR5 0x026
```

After configure the MAC address into those register, then memory dumped those register to confirm that MAC address is properly configured or not.

- prepare DMA tx and rx ring buffer descriptor. I will explain more in detail if you provide the complete gmac data sheet.
- To access the PHY register, we need to configure the ENET GMAC phy management register properly.

Please provide the complete gmac and its PHY data sheet. I will answer more on phy and its operation.